# excel vba - use regex to return information between indicators

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have an app which returns data in the form of a table copied into the clipboard.

the table takes the form of:

```
table name
other info
-------------------------------
|heading 1|heading 2|heading 3|
-------------------------------
|data|date|other Data|
|data|date|other Data|
-------------------------------
time stamp
etc
```

I'm looking to pull back only the heading and data rows, minus the horizontal rows which are represented by dashes (---) in my data.
I need the pipes (|) as they are used to split the rows for passing back to excel.

I've used the following regex attempts

```
strPattern = "(?<=\|)[^|]++(?=\|)"
strPattern = "(\|[^|]++(\|)"
strPattern = "(^\s\|[\d\D]+?\|\s$)"
strPattern = "(^\s\|[\d\D]*\|\s$)"
strReplace = "$1"
```

thinking that the above uses the pipes as bookends and returns any digit or non digit character between the pipes. none of these work and at best it returns the entire string (I know I don't have anything removing the dashes yet)

looking for:

```
|heading 1|heading 2|heading 3|
|data|date|other Data|
|data|date|other Data|
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: So from the above sample; what data exactly are you expecting back? Can you show (not only describe) please?

Comment: Please [edit] into question. Regex it is really important to know layout and exactly what characters are involved e.g. are there newlines?

Comment: the tables can be any number of rows, from 1 to 30,000+ there are new lines at the end of each row.

Comment: Why not just loop through the range, and delete the rows that start with a dash?

Comment: Hi Ron, started out that way but it wasn't very scalable as I'm also doing several other operations on the data so it's getting populated into an array which is more efficient. It's obviously easier to get the data into the array after removing the dash rows and header/ footer sections

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do.  But to create a VBA array consisting of your desired data, you merely need to: Populate array1 in single step:  `array1 = range`: Loop through `array1` and only populate `array2` with lines that start with a `pipe`. Do your array work on `array2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, for a regex that will take your text as a block (multi-line variable) and only return the desired lines, try:

```
^(?:(?:(?:(?=-).)+)|(?:[^|]+))\n?
```

There may be better ways to accomplish your overall goal, but this accomplishes what you requested.

```
Option Explicit
Function PipedLines(S As String)
    Dim RE As Object
    Const sPat As String = "^(?:(?:(?:(?=-).)+)|(?:[^|]+))\n?"

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RE
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = sPat
        PipedLines = .Replace(S, "")
    End With
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: I went with loading the data into a string variable and parsing that into an array as there can be over 300K rows of data so I wanted to keep read/writing to the spreadsheet to a minimum. hence stripping off the unwanted parts of the string to make it easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @tsuimark have you treid copying Clipboard data to directly to excel.?
tried and attched screenshot. and remove unwanted rows in sheet.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: we have been pasting directly into excel but there is some formatting and tiding up to do to make the data useful. I thought creating a right click menu entry and handing the clean up with a macro might make our lives easier.